# Error Status 1 in Arduino MEGA

Tags: compiler-errors, avr, arduino-ide, usart

I have written the following code to receive USART data on Arduino MEGA2560 using reception complete interrupt(ISR) for USART module 1 as I am using USART0 for printing on Serial monitor! The MEGA is interfaced with ESP8266 WiFi module and therefore after sending the AT commands for initialization, the interrupts() is being set! 
The problem is that I get:
"Exit Status 1
Error Compiling for Arduino/Genuino MEGA"

I am using the latest IDE (.12 version) and here is the code.

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h> 
#include <avr/io.h> 

#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUDRATE 9600
#define BAUD_PRESCALER (((F_CPU / (BAUDRATE * 16UL))) - 1)

volatile int i=0;
volatile uint8_t buff[6];
volatile uint8_t StrRxFlag=0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  USART_INIT();
  reset();
  client_set();

}

void USART_INIT(void)
{
    cli();
    UBRR1 = BAUD_PRESCALER;                 // Set the baud rate prescale     rate register
    UCSR1B = ((1<<RXEN1)|(1<<TXEN1)|(1 << RXCIE1));       // Enable receiver and transmitter and Rx interrupt
    UCSR1C = ((0<<USBS1)|(1 << UCSZ11)|(1<<UCSZ10));  // Set frame format: 8data, 1 stop bit. See Table 22-7 for details

}

void reset()
{
  Serial1.println("AT");
  if(Serial1.find("OK")) Serial.println("The module is fine");
}

void client_set()
{
 char a;
 Serial1.println("AT+CWMODE=2");
 delay(1000);
 while(Serial1.available())
 {
    a = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(a);
 }


  Serial1.print("AT+CWJAP=\"new\",\"123\"");    
  //delay(2000);
  while(Serial1.available())
  {
    a = Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(a);
  }


  Serial1.print("AT+CIFSR");
  //delay(1000);
  while(Serial1.available())
  {
    a=Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(a);
  }

  Serial1.print("AT+CIPSERVER=1");
  //delay(1000);
  while(Serial1.available())
  {
    a=Serial1.read();
    Serial.print(a);
  }
 interrupts();
}



void loop() {



}

ISR(USART1_RX_vect)
{
    buff[i]=UDR1;         //Read USART data register
    if(buff[i++]=='\r')   //check for carriage return terminator and  increment buffer index
    {
        // if terminator detected
        if(buff[i]=='\n')
        {
        StrRxFlag=1;        //Set String received flag
        buff[i-1]=0x00;   //Set string terminator to 0x00
        Serial.println("Received data is");
        for(int j=0; j<sizeof(buff);j++)
        {
          Serial.print(buff[j]);
        }
        i=0;                //Reset buffer index
        }
    }
}
```

Please ignore the sending of AT commands using Serial1 as that does not have any relevance! I want to know as to whether there is any mistake in the usage of the interrupt (ISR) and related things.

I am attaching the IDE response after compilation too. Thanks in advance!

[image: The Compiler output]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Arduino Libraries, but looking at the compiler output, my guess is that the ISR may already be defined within the serial port library. There is probably some kind of a callback function to react to incoming data?

The compiler reports something like "Multiple defintion of __vector_36". This normally refers to an ISR being defined more than once, which is illegal.

Lets take a look at the interrupt vector table from the MEGA2560:

```
36 $0046 TIMER3 OVF Timer/Counter3 Overflow   
37 $0048 USART1 RX USART1 Rx Complete
```

The weird thing is, that  vector 36 is the "Timer/Counter3 Overflow" and vector 37 the "USART1 Rx Complete" that should cause the error.